# A mathematical abstraction of colours?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-modeling

Does any formal system exist built upon the mechanics of Additive Colour Theory?

Additive Colour Theory is the description of the behaviour of the visible spectrum of light as it combines-the ""primarys" red, blue and green combining to form the "composites" yellow, cyan and magenta, and these combining to form the "universal" white.

Such a system would be a generalisation of such interactions. Starting at one end with the universal "set" (that corresponds to White in this case), descending with different levels of distinct "sets" of composite elements and ending with the basic element that correspond to red/blue/green. (Disregarding the "colour" black from considerations.)

They can't seem to be modelled for example as sets, as one set can't have two distinct parent sets, unlike the primary, composites and white colour sets in Additive Colour Theory.

The formal definition would involve.
1. a base set of primitive elements
2. increasing levels of layers of elements made from combinations of more basic elements
3. a final universal element that contains all other elements

Comment: You should give information about the additive colour theory, for people are not specialist, and will not try to help you if they have to fill out the blanks by looking elsewhere the information on a field they are not supposed to be specialist on the forum.

Comment: Sorry. Will edit.

Comment: I would say that primary and secondary colors (plus black and white) form a lattice.

Comment: Yes but isn't their combination itself an unique and fundamental concept? Like sets it describes objects that contain other objects, with the one difference being these objects can contained in one more other distinct parent object?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "one set can't have two distinct parent sets", but you can consider the set of colours generated by additive combinations of (a given set of) colours as a [convex cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone). Maybe also take a look at how [colour models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_model) are formalized.

Comment: As far as I understand, for non interesecting sets A and B, a set C can only be contained A or B, but not both. Am I wrong?

Comment: To be snarky: the fact that my computer monitor works means that there are mathematical models of additive colors theory // To be not-snarky: if you want to ask whether a certain formal system exists, you need to give us exactly what the objects are (e.g. just the RGB, CYM, BW colors, or all the colors imaginable) and what are the operators (just the binary mapping from two colors to a third, or something else?). Your parenthetical does very little to address Martigan's comment. // That said, I suspect Rahul has hit the nail on its head already in his comment.

Comment: In your most recent comment, what would correspond to the sets A, B, and C in your imagined system of additive colour theory?

Comment: A, B: composites (yellow/magenta/cyan) C: Primaries (red/blue/green). Eg yellow "contains" red, but so does magenta and both yellow and magenta and are entirely distinct.

Comment: I mean a generalisation of how colours interact. Starting at end with universal set (that corresponds to White in this case), descending with different levels of composite elements and ending with the basic elements. Disregarding black, and the notions of saturation, brightness etc for the time being.

Comment: Rahuls links to a mapping of colours into a "space" which is different. He may be right about mapping a set of composites as a convex cone, but I'm talking more exactly about a formalised foundational definition of the abstraction of colours, which I'll elaborate on in my question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to model? For the physicist colours are just names to certain frequency intervals. What you  probably mean is colour perceived by the human eye where we have trichromacy and different sensitivities of the human eye's colour perceptors. If you want to add another layer about the psychological effects it gets even more complicated.

Comment: I mean simply how colours interact and contain other colours. Red and green combine to form yellow which contains the two, yellow, cyan and magenta combine to form white which contains all 3. This behaviour seems to describe a fundamental mechanism of object interaction (combination) which is separate to that of sets.